# Download Excel using AJAX (POST METHOD) with Flask-Restful Python

Tags: python, ajax, flask

I'm trying to download excel using flask and Ajax, I used POST METHOD because there's many data to passed (JSON). but i got error 'method not allowed' when return excel. But when i used GET METHOD, it can return my excel file, but i can't get my JSON data in server.

Here's my code when i use POST:

```
def post(self):
    
        output = io.BytesIO()
        workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook(output)
        worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()
        filename = 'excel'+".xls"
        worksheet.merge_range('A2:E2', 'WORK!!')
        workbook.close()
        response = make_response(output.getvalue())
        response.headers['Content-Type'] = "application/x-xlsx"
        response.headers["Cache-Control"] = "no-cache"
        response.headers["Content-Disposition"] = "attachment; filename="+filename
        return response
```

here's my ajax code:

```
$.ajax({
  url: '/downloadFile',
  type: 'POST',
  data: JSON.stringify({
    data1: data1,
    data2: data2
  }),
  dataType: "JSON",
  contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
  traditional: true,
  success: function (response) {
    alert('ok')
    window.location = this.url;}})
```

Answer (score 0):

i can't do this thing using AJAX but i tried using XMLHttpRequest and it worked.

```
xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() { 
    var a;
    if (xhttp.readyState === 4 && xhttp.status === 200) {
        a = document.createElement('a');
        a.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(xhttp.response);
        a.download = "-Download"+full_date+".xlsx"
        a.style.display = 'none';
        document.body.appendChild(a);
        a.click();

    }
};
xhttp.open("POST", '/downloadFile/');
xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
xhttp.responseType = 'blob';
xhttp.send(JSON.stringify({ data1: data1, data2: data2}));
```